# Users are accumulating files everywhere and being wasteful/disorganised, what's the best strategy and supporting tools to help clean it up?

Tags: files, user-profile, archive, cleanup

One strategy being considered is:

1. Advise users of the official locations that important working documents should be kept and that files kept in all other locations may be removed at will
2. each month move any files (docx, xlsx etc) not accessed within 1 year to a "safe box"
3. send the user a list of files moved
4. files not restored from the "safe box" will stay there for another year before being removed

Had a quick search for tools to assist i.e. "policy-driven file archiving opensource" etc "EMC SourceOne" appears to be the type of tool that would be useful but not sure if there's an affordable alternative.

Turns out that some scripting may help with our simple needs:

```
robocopy c:\Users\<username>\Desktop c:\trash\<username> /S /COPYALL /minage:7 /XD "Document Library" /MOV /V
```

Move all files older than 7 days to a trash folder except for files in the official "Document Library".

We do have a well-maintained internal website for records management of policies and procedures.

However, there is this small area concerning user's desktops/profiles which we're working on now. We're striving to move as much "spreadsheet managed" records as we can into web apps etc. I guess what we need to manage better is the transition of "active" files used to get a job done immediately into "inactive" files where they may be used as reference sometime in a few months or years.

Comment: What's the real root issue from the sysadmin's POV? Are you trying to use less disk space? Are users themselves complaining about lost files? Is there some security risk involved? Or does it really just boil down to "what a mess, it should look cleaner" ?

Comment: A few issues from multiple POV as you suggest. From a compliance POV, an organisation needs to demonstrate care in protecting sensitive data etc. Minimising disorganised files that may contain sensitive info is just better practice IMHO. Also when employment periods terminate, who wants to wade through people's old junk to see what could be important to the business? Better off using a continual process to ensure people stow things away properly. e.g. you don't want key client correspondence that is contractually binding on an individual's desktop etc. Fewer files are easier to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Given your answer to the question (in comments) about the real issue from sysadmins POV, I'll sketch out the approach I use. It's a combination of clear policy and simple filesystem layout.

The policy: Each user "owns" his/her fileshare. IT doesn't own it; the user does. But like ownership of land within city limits, ownership comes with responsibilities. Clear directives are given as to what may and may not be stored in fileshares. So for example, work-related files may be stored in fileshares;  personal music and movies may not be.

**Conversely, *every* fileshare is owned by some specific person.** This is important. If IT knows who "owns" what, then IT never has to make guesses about the business value of data found in "public" areas. We can merely go to the owner and say something like "Hey, you own this directory full of unknown data; please justify it in business terms or we will delete it."

Each fileshare comes with a quota (maximum size of directory) and that quota is initially set fairly low on purpose, say 200 MB. A fileshare's owner (and only its owner) may request increasement of the quota, but only with a business reason signed off on by the user's boss. IT may audit the directory for policy compliance before increasing quota. IT can look for seemingly unused data and ask owners to justify continued use of the disk space.

When a user leaves the company or changes jobs, his/her user directory, and any \Public or \Project folders, is 'inherited' by their direct supervisor, who is given a specific amount of time (say 14 days) to retrieve or redistribute any data found in that share, or find a new owner for it, before IT deletes it all.

Fileshare layout. Each user gets, by default, something like this example for a user named Bob:

```
\Users\Bob
\Users\Bob\Private (default permissions set so only Bob can read/write here)
\Users\Bob\Public (default permissions set so any employee can read/write here)
```

Bob has full control over permissions, and can create subfolders at need. If he wants to host project data, he can create \Users\Bob\Public\ProjectBlue and set permissions however he wants. With help from IT if he needs it.

At some point, ProjectBlue may outgrow Bob, and be moved to another hierarchy. Say \Public or \Projects or whatever. Which looks like this:

```
\Public\ProjectPurple  (owner: Sam Spade)
\Public\NewEmployeeDocs (owner: current head of HR)
\Public\AdvertisingCampaigns (owner: Pat Seyjak)
... and so on.
```

I'd be *very* wary of running scripted cleanups through filesystems. IT's job is to keep data systems up and running well for business-related reasons, just like Facilities has the job of providing working desks to each employee. Facilities doesn't want employees keeping hamsters in desk drawers, but they don't go around cleaning people's desk drawers for them. Too many ways that can go awry. Imagine how you'd feel if, every month, Facilities went through your drawers and relocated anything they didn't understand to some basement storage locker, forcing you to go down there and reclaim it before they haul all unclaimed stuff to the dump.

We in IT do not know every facet of the business. If we assign ourselves the job of combing through all data and deciding which is business relevant versus which should be sequestered-and-or-deleted, we create many opportunities to make mistakes, interrupt workflows, and create antipathy between us and our users.

But we can create simple rules and organization hierarchies which push responsibility back to where it belongs: the employees closest to whichever facet of the business that generates the data.

Anyway, that's my (lengthy!) two cents. It may or may not apply to your situation.

---

A note: "owner" may be too strong a word. You may need to adjust that to fit company culture. Think "steward" or "assignee" or "principal".

Also, it can be helpful to have certain metrics. For instance, overall yearly capital and maintenance costs of storage are handy. If, for example, you're spending $400k/year on data storage (including equipment, power, backup, service contracts, administration time, etc), and Bob has somehow come to 'own' 22% of all in-use disk space, now you're able to discuss that usage with management, in concrete, understandable terms.

Comment: "We in IT do not know every facet of the business", do you allow an exception for smaller organisations in which the IT function is more closely integrated? I agree on the "being careful." part. Of course, all of this activity needs to occur with consultation and coordination with affected parties.

Comment: I can imagine organizations small enough that IT personnel have a fair understanding of much of the business, yes. But keep that desk analogy in mind. Tidying up everyone's desk (or personal files area) *for* them is, in my opinion anyway, not a good thing for anyone involved. Warning them that their untidiness has exceeded company standards, and they need to cleanup their own stuff, would be a better approach. A script that can do the tidying, could instead just warn them.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it's just one of the facts of user profiles/network shares that users are wasteful/disorganized/etc.

If you're determined to use some kind of tool or script to tidy up, or to delete things in "unofficial" locations, make certain that management is on your side and will back you up.  Ditto if you decide to implement some kind of disk quota.

In other words, I think this is a user rather than a technical problem, and solutions will need a "people" component as well.

Good luck!

(P.S.  Requests for software recommendations are off-topic, so I'm not making any, sorry.)

Comment: Absolutely have management support, there are mistakes being made by people referring to out-of-date documents and files.

Comment: Also I'm not asking for a recommendation, I'm asking for the name of a product or tool of which I'm not yet aware and that I haven't been able to find via usual means.

Comment: @campbeld If I might add, when too many hands are handling the same things it's bound to get messy. I think that there should be one person dealing with each file(s). An internal website might be useful, as it's usually more accessible.
Also: http://xkcd.com/1459/

Comment: (+1 just for the link to xkcd.)

Comment: @EliadTech agreed on the one person per file. However, not everyone is experienced in records management. Also I hear that part of organisational culture includes using mechanisms to encourage behaviours as part of the culture. So surely it will help foster a culture of responsibility for a clean work environment when there is a consistent process highlighting the policy.

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the Desktop and special folder to a network share for each user and run a powershell script to move old file, and you will have the liberty to scan for mp3, or un-allowed file.

Edited: For file that are for a department but user save on their system or in their personnal share, then just copy the user file there and inform the user after if you got a green card to go.

Comment: No trouble accessing the folders. More interested in checking what well-known solutions exist and what works well in others' experience before recreating the wheel. So far it looks like a handful of custom scripts will provide the best result.